# How ArraySlice in Swift work internally?

Tags: arrays, swift

I have already read multiple posts and articles about how `ArraySlice` works with `Array` in `Swift.

But, what I couldn't find is how it works internally? What does **ArraySlice are Views onto Arrays** exactly mean?

```
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
let slice = arr[2...4]

arr.remove(at: 2)
print(slice.startIndex) //2
print(slice.endIndex)   //5
slice[slice.startIndex] //3
```

In the code above, I've removed element at `index-2 (i.e 3)` from `arr`.
`Index-2` is the `startIndex` of `slice` as well.
When I print `slice[slice.startIndex]` it still prints 3.

Since no extra storage is created for `ArraySlice`, then how come any changes in `Array` doesn't reflect in `ArraySlice`?

The articles/ posts can be found here:

https://dzone.com/articles/arrayslice-in-swift

https://marcosantadev.com/arrayslice-in-swift/

Comment: Both Array and ArraySlice are *value types.* As soon as the originating array is mutated, the slice gets its own independent element storage.

Comment: @MartinR Exactly what I meant. But Apple says something else. In its [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice?changes=_5) it says `Neither the firstHalf nor secondHalf slices allocate any new storage of their own. Instead, each presents a view onto the storage of the absences array`.

Comment: That is true only as long as none of them is mutated. (Same COW technique that is used with  arrays and strings.) – If you want the implementation details then you can look at the source code: https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArraySlice.swift.

Comment: @MartinR Then what is the use of strong reference to the original array if it creates a storage of its own?

Comment: The own storage is created only if the array or the slice is mutated. As an example, think of a recursive binary search method: passing the left or right half as a slice to the recursive call creates no extra storage.

Comment: @MartinR Thanks for explaining that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Both `Array` and `ArraySlice` are *value types,* which means that after

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var slice = array[0..<2]
```

`array` and `slice` are independent values, and mutating one does not affect the other:

```
print(slice) // [0, 1]
array.remove(at: 0)
print(slice) // [0, 1]
```

How that is achieved is an implementation detail of the Swift standard library,
but one can inspect the source code to get some ideas: At
[Array.swift#L1241](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Array.swift#L1241)
we find the implementation of `Array.remove(at:)`:

```
  public mutating func remove(at index: Int) -> Element {
    _precondition(index < endIndex, "Index out of range")
    _precondition(index >= startIndex, "Index out of range")
    _makeUniqueAndReserveCapacityIfNotUnique()

   // ...
  }
```

which uses

```
  @inlinable
  @_semantics("array.make_mutable")
  internal mutating func _makeUniqueAndReserveCapacityIfNotUnique() {
    if _slowPath(!_buffer.isMutableAndUniquelyReferenced()) {
      _copyToNewBuffer(oldCount: _buffer.count)
    }
  }
```

Following that trail, we find at [ArrayBuffer.swift#L107](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/ArrayBuffer.swift#L107)

```
  /// Returns `true` iff this buffer's storage is uniquely-referenced.
  @inlinable
  internal mutating func isUniquelyReferenced() -> Bool {

    // ...
  }
```

This isn't the full implementation yet, but (hopefully) already demonstrates that
the (mutating) `remove(at:)` method copies the element storage to a new
buffer if is was shared (with another array or an array slice).

We can also verify that by printing the element storage base address:

```
var array = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
var slice = array[0..<2]

array.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000101927190
slice.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000101927190

array.remove(at: 0)

array.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000101b05350
slice.withUnsafeBytes { print($0.baseAddress!) }  // 0x0000000101927190
```

The same “copy-on-write” technique is used if arrays, dictionaries, or strings
are copied, or if `String` and `Substring` share storage.

So an array slice shares the element storage with its originating
array *as long as neither of them is mutated.*

That is still a useful feature. Here is a simple example:

```
let array = [1, 4, 2]
let diffs = zip(array, array[1...]).map(-)
print(diffs) // [-3, 2]
```

`array[1...]` is a view/slice of the given array, without actually copying
the elements.

A recursive binary search function where slices (of the left or right half) are passed down would be another application.

Answer (score 2):

### Explanation:

Array slice is a view to the underlying array and retains the array.

Probably (not 100% sure), when you remove an element from the array, it is still retained and is just marked as removed.

That is why when you print the array you don't see `3` but the slice still shows it.

### Example:

```
class Car : CustomStringConvertible {
    var description: String {

        let objectIdentifier = ObjectIdentifier(self) //To get the memory address

        return "car instance - \(objectIdentifier) "
    }

    deinit {
        print("car deallocated")
    }
}

var carSlice : ArraySlice<Car>?

var cars : [Car]? = [Car(), Car(), Car()]

carSlice = cars?[0...1]


print("Going to make cars nil")

cars = nil

print("cars     = \(cars?.description ?? "nil")")
print("carSlice = \(carSlice?.description ?? "nil")")

print("----------------")

print("Going to make carSlice nil")

carSlice = nil

print("carSlice = \(carSlice?.description ?? "nil")")
```

#### Output:

```
Going to make cars nil
cars     = nil
carSlice = [car instance - ObjectIdentifier(0x000060c00001e7b0) , car instance - ObjectIdentifier(0x000060c00001e7c0) ]
----------------
Going to make carSlice nil
carSlice = nil
car deallocated
car deallocated
car deallocated
```

### Apple Documentation:

> Long-term storage of ArraySlice instances is discouraged. A slice
>   holds a  reference to the entire storage of a larger array, not just
>   to the portion it  presents, even after the original array’s lifetime
>   ends. Long-term storage of a  slice may therefore prolong the lifetime
>   of elements that are no longer otherwise  accessible, which can appear
>   to be memory and object leakage.

### Refer:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/arrayslice

Comment: *"when you remove an element from the array, it is still retained and is just marked as removed"* – that is not correct. There is no "mark as removed" in Swift arrays.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying I am no expert however I thought internally there must be a way to mark the removed elements because the same memory location was being shared

Comment: In your example, `Car`  is  *value type,* so the array/slice elements are *references/pointers* to the actual instance. Only after the last reference is gone, the instance is deallocated.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR for clarifying

Comment: Sorry, I meant *reference type,* not value type. Classes (and closures) are reference types. struct, enum and tuples are value types.

Comment: Thanks @MartinR, on a completely different note, would be able to help me with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50892967/voice-over-pushes-child-uitableviewcontroller-cell-down